# TM for $0^{5^n}$. Describing a turing machine that decides the language consisting of all strings of zeroes whose length is a power of 5

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

I am trying to describe a TM that decides the language $A=\{0^{5^n} \mid n\ge0\}$.

I know how to do this for $0^{2^n}$, marking off every other 0 in each pass. In my case would it work marking off every fifth 0 in each pass? It would reject if there are an even number of 0s. Every pass reduces the number of 0's by a fifth until there are no more 0s.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna guess you're in s.datta's class?
I am not sure if this is correct but I tried to cross off 4 0's each time instead of 1.
It's like multiplying by 0.2 or the inverse operation of *5)

1*5 = 5
5*5 = 25
25*5 = 125 

125*0.2 = 25
25*0.2 = 5
5*0.2 = 1

Edit: formatting

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct. Essentially what you're doing in each pass is checking that the number of $0$s is a multiple of 5. If it is, you make another pass and if it's not you reject. Here's what happens to the tape when $n=2$:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Initial: } & \mathtt{0000000000000000000000000} \\
\text{After pass 1: } & \mathtt{xxxx0xxxx0xxxx0xxxx0xxxx0}&\text{a multiple of five zeros, so continue} \\
\text{After pass 2: } & \mathtt{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0}&\text{okay so far}\\
\text{After pass 3: } & \mathtt{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0}&\text{done}
\end{align}$$

The idea here is to stop when there's a single zero, since, of course $5^0=1$, so $0^{5^0}=0^1=0\in A$. As usual, there are some further details to deal with, but your idea is correct.